# Install ASP.NET CORE 3.0 extensions inside App Service Environment?

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

Trying to install .NET CORE 3.0 extension for my App Services inside my App Service Environment (ASE):

Using the portal:

[image: A]

I get

[image]

**However the extension is not installed!**

How to get this to work?

Please note: Azure App Services running in App Service Environment

Comment: looks like the rollout has begun... https://twitter.com/timheuer/status/1180182350547886081?s=20

Answer (score 4):

To ensure the extension is installed, in Kudu, check the directory in D:\home\SiteExtensions\AspNetCoreRuntime.3.0.x64.

[image]

Once confirmed you can edit your web.config to point to the site extension as follows as a workaround

```
<aspNetCore processPath="D:\home\SiteExtensions\AspNetCoreRuntime.3.0.x86\dotnet" arguments=".\<project output>.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#webconfig-file for more info.

It does seem this should be handled by the extension itself so there could be a problem there. Nonetheless, .NET Core 3 should be deployed in the next week or so as an available runtime.

**EDIT:**

You add the 'Use .NET Core' task in Azure Pipelines
[image] 
to install the 3.0 SDK. This, in conjunction with `--self-contained true --runtime <RID>` in the Publish task and `<AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>` in your csproj is an alternative to using the extension.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I also read you answer over at MSDN Forum where you said "I've been able to confirm that after installing the .NET Core 3 extension, it still doesn't show as an available runtime. I'll reach out to the team to get an explanation of why."

Comment: @Postlagerkarte right. For some reason, the extension is doing this routing for us that says "hey use this runtime sitting over here". So my answer above is a "workaround" to use 3.0 in an azure app service until the .net core 3.0 rollout is complete and/or the extension is corrected.

Comment: It's been 3 months and it still doesn't work out of the box. They are basically pushing you to use azure pipelines..

Comment: @ThunderDev .NET Core 3 has been deployed to app services. Which region are you deploying to that’s giving you issues?

Comment: @RyanHill-MSFT West Europe

Comment: @ThunderDev - As Ryan points out, the .NET 3.0 (and 3.1) **runtimes** are already deployed worldwide. The App Service team is actively working on getting the SDK installed worldwide too. At this time, you can use CI/CD tools (not just Azure DevOps) to self-contain build your app, then it will run on App Service. Once the 3.1 SDK is deployed, you would be able to build using Kudu.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you could not install it you could go to you app kudu site to install it.

Secondly if you just want to make your .net core 3 web run in Azure, actually there is a tutorial about [how to deploy ASP.NET Core 3.0 to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#deploy-aspnet-core-30-to-azure-app-service).

I test these two, they all could work. Just if you deploy with `Framework-Dependent` way, it will show you a error message like the below pic, however the web will work.

[image]

**Note**:With `Framework-Dependent` way, you have to install the extension, and if you use `Self-Contained` way, you don't have to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update all the extensions that require updates before downloading a new extension in your Azure app service.